# Generics - can not return Base for T with T extends Base

Tags: java, generics, extends

```
public class Testing<T extends Tuple> {

   public T method(){
     return new Tuple(); //Syntax error
   }
}
```

Here is the error I get (syntax error):

```
Incompatible Types:
Required: T
Found: com.company.package1.Tuple
```

Even though I wrote `T extends Tuple` at the start, why am I getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Lets say you have an `IntTuple extends Tuple`, and you want a `Testing<IntTuple>`, but that can't work, because that would make `method()` return an `IntTuple`, but you're creating a `new Tuple()`, and a `Tuple` object cannot be assigned to an `IntTuple`. Re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: That should be an answer!

Comment: This code is indeed pointless, for `T` can only be a `Tuple` itself in order to *not* cause a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

By introducing a generic parameter `T`, you are giving the user of your class the possibility to set a type for you.

Generics act similar as parameters to methods do, but as **type parameters to classes**.

`extends Tuple` is a constraint to the user. So your user is allowed to use `IntTuple` for example. Your method says it returns `T`, but it actually returns just `Tuple`. When the user sets the generic parameter to `IntTuple`, the method would also need to return an `IntTuple`, not a `Tuple`.

---

### Example

Consider the following, slightly more readable example:

```
public class Farm<A extends Animal> {
    public A produce() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

An user can use the farm like this:

```
Farm<Pig> pigFarm = new Farm<>();

Pig pig = produce();
```

The important part here is that `produce` now **must** give out `Pig`s. And if another user has a `Farm<Cow>`, this farm **must** give out `Cow`s.

However, your current implementation was:

```
public A produce() {
    return new Animal();
}
```

But an `Animal` is **not** a `Pig`, nor a `Cow`. So it can not work. It *would* (theoretically) only work if the user would (for whatever reason) use a `Farm<Animal>`.

---

### Solution

It is highly likely that you intended to do something completely different. So, now that you understand the issue, re-think your design.

Maybe you did not even want generics in the first place and just return `Animal`, dropping the `T`.
Maybe you indeed want to return a `T`, but grab the actual `T` instance from elsewhere. Creating a new `T` instance from this method would be quite hard, since you do not know the exact type `T` will be when actually set by the user. A `Cow` might have different constructors than a `Pig`.

---

### Note

Other answers suggest casting to `T`, but this will likely not do what you intended to do. It is the way to make this code somehow compiling. It will then support `Tuple`, but no subclasses. In the example, this reflects the `Farm<Animal>`. And it will fail with a `ClassCastException` for all other inputs. Since an `Animal` can not be casted to a `Pig` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You get compile error since you return `Tuple` from method that has `T` as a return type. At the runtime this `T` may not be a `Tuple`, but some type that extends it. You can cast it to `T`:

```
return (T) new Tuple();
```

After [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) it becomes to `return (Tuple) new Tuple();` since `Tuple` is bound of `T`. That's why it will compiled without any error.

But it will be consider as an **Unchecked cast** and gives you warning. It can lead to `ClassCastException` at execution time when instead of `Tuple` there will be some sub class of `Tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast to T because the method method() must return a object of the type class T

```
 class Testing<T extends Tuple> {

    public T method(){
        return (T) new Tuple()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code as follows to fix this error :

```
public class Testing<T extends Tuple> {
     @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
     public T method(){
          return (T) new Tuple();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

@andreas in the first comment is right. You should ask hem to make his comment an answer and accept it.

Casting a parent to subclass will not work.

Just to make things a bit clearer, look at this example:

```
public class Tuple {
}

public class NamedTuple extends Tuple {
    public String getName() {
        return "NamedTuple";
    }
}

public class Testing<T extends Tuple> {
    public T method(){
        return (T) new Tuple(); // asking for trouble
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final NamedTuple namedTuple = new Testing<NamedTuple>().method();

    // what exactly can be expected here, given that method() creates a Tuple?
    namedTuple.getName();
}
```

What should happen when you call `namedTuple.getName()`? `Testing.method()` has created instance of `Tuple`, but `Tuple` doesn't have a `getName()` method expected from `NamedTuple` class.

Luckily it will never come to this as `method()` will fail with `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because `T` extends `Tuple` doesn't mean that `Tuple` is of type `T`.

Comment: While this is correct, you should probably elaborate on that answer to explain the issue to OP. See [answer], thanks.

Comment: Your answer does a great job of that. I think my answer just provides an extra insight in the simplest of means.